# Google reCaptcha disabled but shop still making request to google

Tags: magento2, captcha, recaptcha

I have disabled Google Recaptcha for Customer and Admin in Magento 2 backend and I also disabled the module with

`bin/magento msp:security:recaptcha:disable`

but no matter which shop page I load, I always see requests towards

`https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1563777128698/recaptcha__de.js`
`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=globalOnRecaptchaOnLoadCallback&render=explicit`

I do not want to have these requests due to GDPR and in general, if I disable a service, I expect this to happen and not having any backdoor which still pulls code from somewhere.

Has someone an idea where these requests are coming from and how I can disable them?

Shop Version: Magento 2.3.2 Open Source

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem we had and were trying the exact same approach you did. In the end, we solved it by not just disabling the module but by uninstalling it. In our case it had a dependency on a PayPal module which we uninstalled as well.

So with the Magento CLI commands:

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_PaypalReCaptcha
bin/magento module:disable MSP_ReCaptcha
```

Followed by the usual:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

From there on, the browser was no longer reporting any kind of calls to google.